# Display text on a html button

Tags: html, css, user-experience

I need to create buttons for two respective labels - Live Server and WebApi like this :
[image]

The numbers displayed on the buttons should be binded through data-bind property. For now, I just want to know how can I display these numbers on the top of each button (without using data-bind).

I have done something like this:

```css
#buttons {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 3px;
  display: flex;
}

.label {
    font-size: medium;
    position: absolute;
}

#l2 {
    width: 100px;
    justify-content:center;
    position: relative;
}

#block2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

small {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
   border: 1px solid black;
}

.stats{
  justify-content: center;
}
.small {
    height: 40px;
    width: 80px;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.button{
    height: 40px;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: flex;

}
```

```html
<div id="block2"><div id="l2"><label class="label label2">WebApi</label></div>
<div id ="buttons">
       <div class="button">
            <div><button class="k-button button5 small" id="b5" >PUT</button></div>
            <div class="stats"><small>10</small></div>
       </div>

       <div class="button">
            <div><button class="k-button button6 small" id="b6">POST</button></div>
            <div class="stats"><small>30</small></div>
       </div>

       <div class="button">
            <div><button class="k-button button7 small" id="b7">GET</button></div>
            <div class="stats"><small>16</small></div>
       </div>

       <div class="button">
            <div> <button class="k-button button8 small" id="b8">PENDING</button></div>
            <div class="stats"><small>25</small></div>
       </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share full relevant code, as your code doesn't contain a single `data-bind`

Comment: Add a `span` tag inside your button where the number will be placed. https://jsfiddle.net/ewnx1g0L/

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I have mentioned that I just want to know how can I display the number on the button without using data-bind. I just want to know the basic html and css part of it

Comment: @MattHamer5 Thank You. This is pretty much what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on a right track just put that number `div` inside that `button` and use `flex`

```css
#buttons {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 3px;
  display: flex;
}

.label {
    font-size: medium;
    position: absolute;
}

#l2 {
    width: 100px;
    justify-content:center;
    position: relative;
}

#block2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

small {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
   border: 1px solid black;
}

.stats{
  justify-content: center;
}
.small {
    height: 40px;
    width: 80px;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.button{
    height: 40px;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: flex;

} 
.k-button{
  display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 min-width: 100px;
}

}
```

```html
<div id="block2"><div id="l2"><label class="label label2">WebApi</label></div>
<div id ="buttons">
       <div class="button">
            <div><button class="k-button button5 small" id="b5" >PUT  <div class="stats"><small>30</small></div></button></div>
            
       </div>

       <div class="button">
            <div><button class="k-button button6 small" id="b6">POST <div class="stats"><small>30</small></div></button></div>
           
       </div>

       <div class="button">
            <div><button class="k-button button7 small" id="b7">GET<div class="stats"><small>16</small></div></button></div>
            
       </div>

       <div class="button">
            <div> <button class="k-button button8 small" id="b8">PENDING<div class="stats"><small>25</small></div></button></div>
            
       </div>
</div>
</div>
```